# Django reverse url failing

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I have a url

```
url(r"^app/get/(?P<param>[1-9]+)/$", AppView.as_view(), name="app_view")
```

And i have a reverse statement as follows

```
["<a href='{0}'>App</a>".format(reverse("app_view", kwargs={"param": self.id}))]
```

Here `self` is the model object. Now the reverse match fails for some model objects and works for some (Surprising).I am using django1.3

Comment: Reverse for 'app_view' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'param': 1052L}' not found. And it works for some other model objects

Comment: You **must not** use Django 1.3. That version has been unsupported for at least four years and is therefore totally insecure. Upgrade to the latest supported version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is missing the number 0

```
?P<param>[1-9]+
```

should be

```
?P<param>[0-9]+
```

or just

```
?P<param>\d+
```